# Prove a field - trouble with defining basic operations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm certain this is a fairly easy question, but my algebra is rusty and I'm doing this as a part of a bigger proof.

I'm stating that, if $\Bbb K$ is a field and $\Bbb K'$ its prime subfield, then

1) If $char(\Bbb K)=0$, then $\Bbb K'$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

2) If $char(\Bbb K)=p$,   $p \in \Bbb N$,  then $\Bbb K'$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$.

As my teacher put it, this is a rather long proof. We start by introducing another group.

- With 1 the identity element of $\Bbb K$, let us define $\Bbb K_0 = \{m_1*1(n_1*1)^{-1}: m,n \in \Bbb Z, n*1 ≠ 0\}$.

Aaaaand I'm stuck in the first step, which is proving $\Bbb K_0$ is a field.

- $\Bbb K_0\subset \Bbb K$, by construction - (no idea why...?)
- $a,b \in \Bbb K$, so $a=m*1(n*1)^{-1}$ and $b=m'*1(n'*1)^{-1}$

And here's where I'm having trouble:

$a*b^{-1} = m*1(n*1)^{-1}*n'*1(m'*1)^{-1}$

$=  \ \ ...$

So, I'm a bit unsure what to do now. Should I apply associative and distributive properties to get results like n*m', which I know belongs to $\Bbb Z$?

I'm sorry. My algebra is **really** rusty.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a prime subfield ?

Comment: According to my teacher, a prime subfield is such field that contains no subfields other than itself and the empty subfield; in other words, we say it has no "proper subfields" - not sure if the same nomenclature applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do, is show $(\Bbb K_0,+)$ is a group, under addition (it *won't* be a group under multiplication).

Since elements of $\Bbb K_0$ are just "elements of a certain form" in $\Bbb K$, $\Bbb K_0$ is certainly a *subset* of $\Bbb K$. What I would do first, is show that:

$(m\ast 1)(n \ast 1)^{-1} + (m'\ast 1)(n'\ast 1) = ((mn' + m'n)\ast 1)((nn')\ast 1)$

To show this lies in $\Bbb K_0$ you will need to show that $(nn')\ast 1 \neq 0$.

We "inherit" associativity and commutativity from $\Bbb K$'s addition, so you don't need to prove those.

Show that $(0\ast 1)(1\ast 1)^{-1}$ is an additive identity, and that $(m\ast 1)(n\ast 1)^{-1} = 0 \iff m\ast 1 = 0$ (note that several different integer $m$'s might produce the zero-element of $\Bbb K$ if it has non-zero characteristic).

Finally, show that $(-m\ast 1)(n\ast 1)^{-1}$ is an additive inverse for $(m\ast1)(n\ast1)^{-1}$.

Having done all that, it remains to be seen that $\Bbb K_0 - \{0\}$ is a group under multiplication. Again, you will need to show that:

$(m\ast 1)(n\ast 1)^{-1}(m'\ast 1)(n'\ast 1)^{-1} = ((mm')\ast 1)((nn')\ast 1)^{-1}$. What must you show to see this lies again in $\Bbb K_0$?

Having shown closure, you must exhibit an identity, and the existence of inverses (commutativity, associativity and the distributive law will all inherit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll use this to practice my algebra!